# Folder ownership and permission issue in debian

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I am having an issue with a wordpress install.  The wordpress was installed as admindm:www-data.  In order for me to install any plugins or themes i have to change the ownership like this www-data:www-data.  With that method my FTP stops working and I have to revert back to the previous.

How can I get it all to work with www-data:www-data?

User admindm is part of www-data group so im missing something here

```
$ ls -l
total 13052
-rw-r--r-- 1 admindm admindm 13360907 Dec 12 21:34 latest.zip
drwxr-xr-x 5 admindm www-data        4096 Dec 18 18:57 wordpress
```

Comment: `User admindm is part of www-data group so im missing something here` while permissions for the www-data user and the www-data group are different

Comment: @TomYan Im not following what your putting down.

Comment: Start from here: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/